# This restaurant has become popular in recent years. (event or process?)

Tags: phrase-meaning, present-tense

Does the sentence

> This restaurant has become popular in recent years.

imply an ongoing, continuous process (becoming popular) that has been happening during the recent years? Or does it mean that it just happened some time ago, maybe quickly, but not earlier than a few years ago?

Comment: This is a good question, but seems more philosophical than linguistic to me. Is popularity something that exists on a spectrum and can happen gradually, or is popularity just a binary (popular vs. not popular)? I think both interpretations make sense.

Comment: As for me it's more a question about "has become" + "in recent years". I suppose it's the "in recent years" what makes that sentence imply a ongoing process as a possible meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The [present perfect tense](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html) shows a action that has taken place over *some* time and may *still be ongoing*. It may be used to show continual change, e.g. `in recent years`.

This is as opposed to the simple past, e.g. `This restaurant became popular overnight.`

Comment: I don't think I agree with your answer, for example the sentence "We've eaten at that restaurant in recent years" doesn't describe "a change that has taken place over some time" or "a continual change".

Comment: @embedc, agreed, `action` is better than `change`. However, see the citation linked above, "to show that an action has taken place once or many times before now."

Answer (score -1):

This restaurant has become popular in recent years.

meaning:

> The restaurant became popular in the years that just passed recently for instance it is currently 2021 meaning the restaurant would have become popular in the years of 2020 and 2019 the current closest years to 2021 meaning recently

means it already happened